# Url no htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess

É possível controlar a url no htaccess?
Por exemplo: se digitar site.com.br ele corrige e coloca o www.site.com.br.

Estou com um caso que algumas páginas vão com site.com.br/blog.
Outras com site.com.br/quem-somos dão erro, pois ele manda para
https://site.com/index.php.

O htaccess que estou usando é este:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

(Desculpem, mas não encontrei outra forma de colocar aqui).

Answer (score 0):

Você está redirecionando do *http* para o *https* corretamente. Agora você precisa redirecionar para o domínio correto:

```
# Redirecionando do domínio errado (sem www) para o correto (com www)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. # Verifica se tem o www
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Coloque isso depois da sua última regra, isto é, depois de `RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`.

Comment: Fiz isso e agora vai para https://www.site.com.br/index.php. Será que tem mais algum bo?

Comment: O seu site é esse mesmo? Por que a URL está certinha https://www.site.com.br/index.php

Comment: Posso colocar a url real? Achei que não podia.

Comment: Pode, mas é melhor deixar as variáveis de ambiente mesmo.